# RegEx to capture sub group that uses the same parent tags

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm having a bit of trouble capturing multiple groups due to the fact that the groups use the same parent tags.

The block of data looks like this (I've split the lines for readability, *the actual data has no line breaks*)

```
<w:p w:rsidR="100"><w:r><w:p w:rsidR="250"><w:r><w:t>Phrase 1</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:r><w:r><w:t>Phrase 2</w:t></w:r></w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="500"><w:r><w:p><w:r><w:t>Phrase 1</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:r><w:r><w:t>Phrase 2</w:t></w:r></w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="150"><w:r><w:p w:rsidR="51"><w:r><w:t>Phrase 1</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:r><w:r><w:t>Phrase 2</w:t></w:r></w:p>
<w:p><w:r><w:p w:rsidR="2"><w:r><w:t>Phrase 1</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:r><w:r><w:t>Phrase 2</w:t></w:r></w:p>
<w:p w:hi="150"><w:r><w:p w:hi="5"><w:r><w:t>Phrase 1</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:r><w:r><w:t>Phrase 2</w:t></w:r></w:p>
```

The original regex dies due to the fact that the sub tag ends in the same root ending tag (due to the lazy lookahead - which is what we want because the blob of data is more than one):

```
/(<w:p .*?>|<w:p>)(.*?)<\/w:p>/
```

So it never captures the the data beyond: "Text Group 2...".

Bracket usage will not work since the sub tag is also dynamic i.e. `(<w:p .*?>|<w:p>)`

Negative lookahead group should do the trick here, but I must have something mixed up?  This yields no valid result.

```
/(<w:p .*?>|<w:p>)(.*?(?!(<w:p .*?>|<w:p>).*?<\/w:p>))<\/w:p>/
```

Using a non capturing group did get the lazy quantier to the end however it doesn't (obviously) capture the first portion:

```
(<w:p .*?>|<w:p>)((?:((<w:p .*?>|<w:p>).*?<\/w:p>)).*?)<\/w:p>
```

The desired output is for the 2nd capturing group to contain all of the following:

```
<w:r><w:p w:rsidR="250"><w:r><w:t>Phrase 1</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:r><w:r><w:t>Phrase 2</w:t></w:r>
```

Note this is not the same as [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), the tags are identified here and are a constant.

Comment: You should really parse it with an XML Parser, they are designed to do this stuff.

Comment: @AlexK. that was my first attempt, it didn't work correctly with my experiment.  It's definitely feasible in regex.

Comment: I really can't understand what you try to achieve. Output isn't clear.

Comment: @revo i've updated the post.  The output is everything between <w:p> to </w:p>, including the <w:p>'s in-between.

Comment: it won't work if you try to use regex to capture context free grammar.

Comment: @CAustin because the blob of data is not always XML valid and will not parse... Regex is a extensible solution for this problem.

Comment: this just implies you need more sophisticated and customized parser.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr or something sophisticated such as regex to pull it off?

Comment: you must need to know your data better. obviously, if your data is not even well formed, there isn't a way to begin with. either fix your data, or if it's out of your control, try to get something more complicated. regex is the least complex language, so it might not satisfy your need.

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://regex101.com/r/CLy6SY/1 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr obviously the data needs to be consistent, the constant here is ASCII.

Comment: @CAustin not a dupe, there is a constant in place for the data desired.

Comment: @revo close! Let me see what I can do with that.

Comment: That may be close though... never follow it.

Comment: I've simplified the data and updated the desired output for easier understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the **branch reset group** **?|** which allowed me to combine the sub pattern + wildcard while using the lazy operator to find the tail.

Example:

```
<w:p[^>]*>((?|(<w:p[^>]*>.*?<\/w:p>)|(.))*?)<\/w:p>
```